# How to sync a list of instances to an original list of instances in Python?

Tags: python, list, instance

I have a data manager class that contains an original list of data instances. I also have a GUI class that contains GUI elements for each of these instances. I need to sync up the GUI list with the original list when an event occurs.

I feel like there is a better, more elegant solution to this than looping through both lists to append() and remove() specific instances.

Edit: an example case would be

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name='default'):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


a = Foo(name='a')
b = Foo(name='b')
c = Foo(name='c')
d = Foo(name='d')

l_original = [a, b]
l_synced = [a, b, c]
```

In this case I would want an algorithm that makes sure that l_synced is the same as l_original **without** setting l_synced = l_original.

Comment: Could you provide example? It's hard to say anything about example/code...

Comment: Generally speaking: remove all state from the GUI class.

Comment: @milanbalazs I added an update with an example case.

Comment: What would be the result of this sync? A union?

Comment: If you don't want `l_synced` and `l_original` to refer to the same underlying list, then set `l_synced = list(l_original)` which will make a (shallow) copy of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave a reference in the GUI model back to the data instance. Then when event occur I would loop through all GUI instances and using a reference they have back to the real data instance invoke on said data instance a relevant method like `delete()`,`modify()` etc. Also I would pass a reference to some kind of `Factory()` class that could create new instances of data model to the GUI element responsible for addition of elements.

Answer (score 0):

An example for to make sure that `l_synced` is the same as `l_original` without setting l_synced = l_original. It uses append and remove. I hope it can help you.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name='default'):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


a = Foo(name='a')
b = Foo(name='b')
c = Foo(name='c')
d = Foo(name='d')

l_original = [a, b]
l_synced = [a, b, c]

print("Before")
print("Original: %s" % l_original)
print("Synced: %s" % l_synced)

for sync_obj in l_synced:
    if sync_obj in l_original:
        print("%s in l_original" % sync_obj)
    else:
        print("%s NOT in l_original. Remove it." % sync_obj)
        l_synced.remove(sync_obj)

for orig_obj in l_original:
    if orig_obj in l_synced:
        print("%s in l_synced" % orig_obj)
    else:
        print("%s NOT in l_synced. Append it." % orig_obj)
        l_synced.sppend(orig_obj)

print("After")
print("Original: %s" % l_original)
print("Synced: %s" % l_synced)
```

Output:

```
>>>python loop.py 
Before
Original: [a, b]
Synced: [a, b, c]
a in l_original
b in l_original
c NOT in l_original. Remove it.
a in l_synced
b in l_synced
After
Original: [a, b]
Synced: [a, b]
```